# Send Mouse Coordinates Over Tcp Issues

Tags: c#, winforms, tcpclient

I am working on program in which I want to move cursor of remote pc from my pc but here is a little problem receiving mouse coordinates on remote pc the data receive by tcp server on remote machine due to delay not pushing immediately on some places here is the code and output coordinates which i saved in a file for both client send and server receive.

Client Code to Send Coordinates.

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isconnected)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            int pX = Cursor.Position.X;
            int pY = Cursor.Position.Y;
            byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{pX}#{pY}");
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"F:\DOWNLOAD\client.txt", $"{pX}#{pY}" + Environment.NewLine);
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
            serverStream.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Server Code to Receive Coordinates

```
while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
{
    try
    {
        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
        // Receive mouse coordinates here
        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

        string Coordinates = data.ToString();
        string X = Coordinates.Substring(0, Coordinates.IndexOf('#'));
        string Y = Coordinates.Substring(Coordinates.IndexOf('#') + 1);
        coordvalue.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => coordvalue.Text = ""));

        coordvalue.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => coordvalue.Text = $"{X} and {Y}"));
        coordvalue.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => coordvalue.Update()));

        // Change coordinates
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(X), Convert.ToInt32(Y));
        Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"F:\DOWNLOAD\server.txt", $"{X} and {Y}" + Environment.NewLine);

    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        //  MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
    }
}
```

Send Coordinates from client

653#492
659#490
669#489
677#486
684#483
693#476
699#470
709#460
715#453
720#444
724#437

Receive Coordinates on Server
653 and 492
659 and 490
669 and 489
677 and 486
684 and 483
693 and 476
699 and 470
709 and 460715#453720#444
724 and 437

Here problem is with**709 and 460715#453720#444** because old coordinates were not pushed forward and appending with new which is not suitable for mouse position Please help.

Comment: You might be better served with a UDP solution that doesn't buffer and resend - just gets info out as fast as possible.  As long as mouse position is sent over and over, if you drop a packet once in a while, no big deal.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelDorgan I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for this situation using binary format is better.

Like this:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (isconnected)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

            var BW = new BinaryWriter(serverStream);

            this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            int pX = Cursor.Position.X;
            int pY = Cursor.Position.Y;
            BW.Write(pX);
            BW.Write(pY);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }
    }

}

private void RecieveLoop()
{
    if (clientSocket.Available > 0)
    {
        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        var BR = new BinaryReader(serverStream);

        try
        {
            int X = BR.ReadInt32();
            int Y = BR.ReadInt32();


            coordvalue.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => coordvalue.Text = ""));

            coordvalue.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => coordvalue.Text = $"{X} and {Y}"));
            coordvalue.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => coordvalue.Update()));
            ////change coordinates
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(X), Convert.ToInt32(Y));
            Cursor.Clip = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"F:\DOWNLOAD\server.txt", $"{X} and {Y}" + Environment.NewLine);

        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {

            //  MessageBox.Show(E.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you sending both the binary and string representation over the connection?

Comment: Yes, you are right. string representation must be removed.

Answer (score 0):

while you have a delimiter between x and y, you don't pass a delimiter between messages and instead rely on timing, which as you've discovered isn't reliable. Add a delimiter or an "end of message" marker after the y value and parse for it on the server to ensure you didn't get two messages at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

you problem is that you are treating TCP like a block protocol. It is not, TCP is a streaming protocol. The only guarantee is that you send some bytes and that they will be received in the same order. You could send one chunk of 100 bytes and receive 50 2 bytes chunks, or 1 100 byte, or 100 1 byte message. You need to be able to read the stream and know how much data you need and to block until you have read it all.

I would use c# binary writer / reader. That prepends length information and the receive will wait till it has everything.